# What is the difference between the standard errors calculated by predict.lm() and summary.lm()

Tags: r, prediction, lm, anova

I am trying to calculate standard errors of group means for a two-way-anova. I found two ways to do this (`predict.lm(, se = T)` and `summary.lm()`:

```
set.seed(42234)
exmpl <- data.frame(DV = rnorm(40) + rep(3:6 * 10, each = 10), #  Dependent Variable
                    IV1 = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 20)), # Independent Variable (Treatment) 1 
                    IV2 = factor(rep(rep(LETTERS[3:4], each = 10), 2))) #  Independent Variable (Treatment) 2

exmpl.lm <- lm(DV ~ IV1 + IV2, data = exmpl) #  Example data was generated without interactions

summary(exmpl.lm)
as.data.frame(predict(exmpl.lm, data.frame(IV1 = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B'),
                                           IV2 = c('C', 'C', 'D', 'D')), se = T))
```

The standard errors of some group means differ. I managed to recalculate the standard errors given by `predict()` with the explanations from [Practical Regression and Anova using R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf) from Faraway (section 3.5). I couldn't find any information about the algorithms used by the `summary()` function. Any ideas?
 What I find really confusing is that you can change the output by relabelling one factor:

```
exmpl2 <- exmpl
exmpl2$IV1 <- factor(exmpl2$IV1, levels = LETTERS[2:1])

exmpl2.lm <- lm(DV ~ IV1 + IV2, data = exmpl2)
summary(exmpl2.lm)
summary(exmpl.lm)
```

In the first example group A-C has a standard error of 0.2013. In the second example the standard error is given as 0.2324. The data of both examples is the same, only the order of the labels of a categorial (not ordinal) variable were changed. How does this influence the statistical model?

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly are you confused about? That standard errors of parameters are a different quantity than standard errors of predictions? How treatment contrasts are handled by `lm`? Why have you tagged this "anova"?

Answer (score 3):

The standard errors are the same for both of your models.

**exmpl.lm:**

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  30.2917     0.2013  150.48   <2e-16 ***
IV1B         19.6148     0.2324   84.39   <2e-16 ***
IV2D         10.1140     0.2324   43.51   <2e-16 ***
```

**exmpl2.lm:**

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  49.9065     0.2013  247.93   <2e-16 ***
IV1A        -19.6148     0.2324  -84.39   <2e-16 ***
IV2D         10.1140     0.2324   43.51   <2e-16 ***
```

The only difference between these two models are the intercept terms. In the first model, the intercept term is an estimate of the mean when `IV1` is `'A'` and `IV2` is `'C'`:

```
> mean(exmpl[exmpl$IV1 == 'A' & exmpl$IV2 == 'C', "DV"])
[1] 30.37096
```

In the second model, the intercept term is an estimate of the mean when `IV1` is `'B'` and `IV2` is `'C'`:

```
> mean(exmpl[exmpl$IV1 == 'B' & exmpl$IV2 == 'C', "DV"])
[1] 49.82731
```

Your standard errors generated by `predict` are not different from the intercept standard errors. The predictions correspond to the estimated means (intercepts) for the different combinations of `IV1` and `IV2`.

```
       fit    se.fit df residual.scale
1 30.29173 0.2012963 37        0.73503
2 49.90654 0.2012963 37        0.73503
3 40.40573 0.2012963 37        0.73503
4 60.02053 0.2012963 37        0.73503
```